# How much dark energy will fit in an average cup of coffee?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dark-energy

I am looking for the answer in Joules for obvious reasons.

Comment: This would presumably be the volume density of the dark energy multiplied by the volume of the cup. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It's not clear to me what "fit in" means in this context.  Do you just mean how much dark energy would we expect in that volume?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dark energy as expressed by the cosmological constant is, as the name implies, a constant of space. Therefore, in a cup of coffee, we get, for some static observer $t$, and a spacelike hypersurface $\Sigma$ (I'm assuming that in our universe, there exists a neighbourhood that can be foliated in spacelike hypersurfaces large enough to accommodate a coffee cup) on which we do the actual volume integration,

\begin{eqnarray}
E &=& \int_☕ T_{\mu\nu} t^\mu t^\nu d\mu[g_\Sigma]\\
&=& \int_☕ - \frac{c^4}{8\pi G} \Lambda g(t,t) d\mu[g_\Sigma]
\end{eqnarray}

If we consider the cosmological constant as part of the stress-energy tensor, $T'_{\mu\nu} = T_{\mu\nu} - \frac{c^4}{8\pi G} \Lambda g_{\mu\nu}$. A cup of coffee is [fairly small](http://www.thepapercupcompany.com/html/cup_dimensions.html)

[image]

We can without much loss of experimental precision consider some Riemann normal coordinates around the center of the cup, so that $g \approx \eta$ (and, on $\Sigma$, that it is just the Euclidian metric) in the neighbourhood of the cup (Any extra term will be $\approx \mathcal{O}(l^3)$ here, with $l$ the characteristic dimension of the cup). Therefore, picking the canonical static observer $t^\mu = (1,0,0,0)$, this gives us

$$E = \frac{c^4}{8\pi G} \Lambda \int_☕ d^3x = \frac{c^4}{8\pi G} V \Lambda$$

In other words, we just have the volume by the cosmological constant. Given the current Lambda-CDM model of our universe, $\Lambda$ is estimated at

$$\Lambda = 1.1056 \times 10^{-52}\ \text{m}^{-2} $$

Unfortunately, the cosmological constant doesn't seem to have the uncertainty written down. This is due to the fact that in actual cosmology work, people generally use the dark energy density instead, $\Omega_\Lambda$, which we have as (cf particle data group)

$$\Omega_\Lambda = 0.692 \pm 0.012$$

The general formula relating the density parameter to its density, in the $\Lambda$CDM model, is

$$\Omega_\Lambda = \frac{8\pi G \rho_\Lambda(t = t_0)}{3 H_0^2}$$

So

$$\rho_\Lambda(t = t_0) = \frac{3 \Omega_\Lambda H_0^2}{8\pi G}$$

Where we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\pi &=& 3.141592653 \pm 0.0000000005\\
G &=& (6.674 08 \pm 0.00031) \times 10^{-11} \text{m}^3 \cdot \text{kg}^{−1}\cdot \text{s}^{−2}\\
H_0 &=& (0.2197 \pm 0.027) \times 10^{-17} s^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray}

Using rough uncertainty propagation, this gives us

\begin{equation}
(\Delta \rho_\Lambda)^2 = \rho_\Lambda^2 \left[(\frac{\Delta \pi}{\pi})^2 + 4 (\frac{\Delta H_0}{H_0})^2 + (\frac{\Delta \Omega_\Lambda}{\Omega_\Lambda})^2\right]
\end{equation}

so that

\begin{equation}
\rho_\Lambda = (0.59739 \pm 0.0734) \times 10^{-26} \text{m}^{-3} \cdot \text{kg}
\end{equation}

For some reason this formula doesn't actually give us the energy density as it's only equivalent to our formula up to a factor of $c^2$, so we get

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{c^4}{8\pi G} \Lambda &=& c^2 \rho_\Lambda
&=& (5.36907 \pm 0.65968) \times 10^{-10}\ \text{J}\cdot\text{m}^{-3}
\end{eqnarray}

That's roughly the same value we'd get from our value of $\Lambda$, but with uncertainty.

A medium coffee cup, as shown here, is about (assuming an error of every dimension of about $\approx 0.5 mm$), $(0.34 \pm 0.0015)\ \text{L}$, or $(0.34 \pm 0.0015)\times 10^{-3}\ \text{m}^3$, so this gives us

$$E_{\Lambda ☕} = (1.810220805 \pm 0.22255)\times 10^{-13}\ \text{J}$$

We've dragged around a lot of digits for the calculations, now let's cut them off to significant figures : the smallest number of significant figures in our values is the dark energy density, at 3 significant figures. Therefore, we can cut off everything at that point.

$$E_{\Lambda ☕} = (1.81 \pm 0.22)\times 10^{-13}\ \text{J}$$

As an exercise left to the reader, compute the energy as measured by an observer running to a coffee cup with speed $\beta = 0.1$

Comment: Great answer! Every student should know this facts.